# use smo to clone azure SQL database?

Tags: clone, azure-sql-database, restore, smo

I'm writing a program to test update scripts for Azure sql.
The idea is to
 - first clone a database (or fill a clone with the source schema and content)
 - then run the update script on the clone

Locally I have this working, but for azure I have the probem that I don't see any file names. If I restore one database to another on the same azure "server", don't I have to rename the data files during restore too?

For local restore I do this:

```
restore.Devices.AddDevice(settings.BackupFileName, DeviceType.File);
restore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile("<db>", Path.Combine(settings.DataFileDirectory, settings.TestDatabaseName + ".mdf")));
restore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile("<db>_log", Path.Combine(settings.DataFileDirectory, settings.TestDatabaseName + "_1.ldf")));
restore.SqlRestore(srv);
```

Is something similar required for cloning a database on azure?

Lots of Greetings!
Volker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a database as a copy of [[source]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268335.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name [ COLLATE collation_name ]
| AS COPY OF [source_server_name].source_database_name

{
   (<edition_options> [, ...n]) 
}

<edition_options> ::= 
{
      MAXSIZE = { 100 MB | 500 MB | 1 | 5 | 10 | 20 | 30 … 150…500 } GB  
    | EDITION = { 'web' | 'business' | 'basic' | 'standard' | 'premium' } 
    | SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 
          {  'basic' | 'S0' | 'S1' | 'S2' | 'S3' 
            | 'P1' | 'P2' | 'P3' | 'P4'| 'P6' | 'P11' 
            | { ELASTIC_POOL(name = <elastic_pool_name>) } } 
}
[;]
```

Comment: Well, that was _almost_ it. 2 more things: First one need to poll the server until the database shows up in the sys.databases view with the correct status. Then one needs to poll again until the database actually shyows up in the smo database collection. _Then_ one can use the database. And, of course, if one does that too frequently, the copy process may hang at any time.